# Sophos UTM virtual appliance VM in DMZ

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, port-forwarding, dmz, sophos

How safe would it be for a 'VM' Virtual Appliance UTM Sophos Firewall to be in DMZ. Can its security get compromised while the VM is in DMZ.. Im planning on such a setup for VPN access and certain port forwarding.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to set up the 'VM' for connectivity outside the VM in order for network traffic to flow, so then security for the VM inside DMZ will be the same as for a physical machine inside DMZ.

No special increased security for using a VM.

Comment: so the IP address of the Virtual Sophos UTM Firewall 'VM' would be the DMZ IP at a Router.. Currently Im using a TP-link VPN Router

Comment: Even so, the VM needs connectivity, so no added security (your question).